# hiding jquery table columns with header anchor text value

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I am trying to hide Table columns using jquery based on table>th>a text. My code only hides header and not the td columns related to header. I used to get index of th also but cant get exact solution. Could some one please help me on this issue. [This is what I tried in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6L5Jd/1/)

```
Enter th names seperated by commas
<input type=text id=thVal >
    <input type=button value='hide entered th related columns' id=btnclick>
<div id="tblMyProjects1" class="flexcroll">
    <table id="tblMyProjects" width=100%>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/Default/MyProjects?sort=ID&amp;sortdir=ASC">ID</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/Default/MyProjects?sort=Title&amp;sortdir=ASC">Title</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/Default/MyProjects?sort=ProjectType&amp;sortdir=ASC">ProjectType</a>            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Test Project ALTERED</td>
            <td>test1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Test Project</td>
            <td>test2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>Test Project</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>pJPgOjDP</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>Tve4Odmmm</td>
            <td>test 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>MDq6pQZG4Y</td>
            <td>tst 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>hkfeIDz06Z</td>
            <td>test 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>TestAutomationeHuthBrG</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>TestAutomationZIv8k48KJv</td>
            <td>test7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>TestAutomationjy6J8FrD</td>
            <td>testing</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

</div>




function hidecolumn(columns) {
    var table = $('#tblMyProjects');
    var findColumn = $(table.find('th:contains(' + columns + ')'));
    var index = findColumn.index();
    findColumn.hide();
    $(table.find('tbody td:eq(' + index + ')')).hide();
}

$('#btnclick').click(function(){
    $('#tblMyProjects > tbody').each(function(){
hidecolumn($('#thVal').val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got solution for my question. I am posting it here so that it will be useful for other developer.

[solution](http://jsfiddle.net/6L5Jd/5/)

```
Enter th names seperated by commas
<input type=text id=thVal >
    <input type=button value='hide entered th related columns' id=btnclick>
<div id="tblMyProjects1" class="flexcroll">
    <table id="tblMyProjects" width=100%>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/Default/MyProjects?sort=ID&amp;sortdir=ASC">ID</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/Default/MyProjects?sort=Title&amp;sortdir=ASC">Title</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/Default/MyProjects?sort=ProjectType&amp;sortdir=ASC">ProjectType</a>            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Test Project ALTERED</td>
            <td>test1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>Test Project</td>
            <td>test2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12</td>
            <td>Test Project</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>pJPgOjDP</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>14</td>
            <td>Tve4Odmmm</td>
            <td>test 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>MDq6pQZG4Y</td>
            <td>tst 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>hkfeIDz06Z</td>
            <td>test 5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>17</td>
            <td>TestAutomationeHuthBrG</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>18</td>
            <td>TestAutomationZIv8k48KJv</td>
            <td>test7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>TestAutomationjy6J8FrD</td>
            <td>testing</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
function hidecolumn(columns) {
    var table = $('#tblMyProjects');
    var findColumn = $(table.find('th:contains(' + columns + ')'));
    var index = findColumn.index();
    var tds;
    findColumn.hide();
    $(table).find('tr').each(function(key, value) {
        tds = $(this).find('td');
        $(tds).each(function(tdkey, tdval) {
            if(tdkey == index)
                $(this).hide();
        });
    });
}
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#btnclick').click(function(){
   var array = $('#thVal').val().split(',');    
$.each(array,function(i){
    alert(array[i]);
hidecolumn(array[i]);    
});       
});
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

My example is possibly a little longer than necessary, but outlines the logic required pretty well.

You already have the required index, so I'm looping through all rows, then looping through all children `td` elements and removing any that have the same index:

```
var tds;
$(table).find('tr').each(function(key, value) {
    tds = $(this).find('td');
    $(tds).each(function(tdkey, tdval) {
        if(tdkey == index)
            $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6L5Jd/2/

**Note:** they still exist in the DOM, if you want to get rid of them completely, you should use `.remove()` instead of `.hide()`

Comment: This seems to be awesome, but I am blocked to loop values based on multiple entries in textbox separated by commas. Could you please throw some ideas on that part?

Comment: This is what I tried
 $('#btnclick').click(function(){
    var array = $('#thval').val().split(",");
    $.each(array,function(i){
    hidecolumn($(array[i]).val());    
 });

Comment: Please note the contains selector is case sensitive "id" is not Equivalent to "ID".